# Convert List of Objects to Hash

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I have a list of objects called `Things` with an `Id` property and a `value` property.

I want to make a Hash that contains `Id` as the key and `Value` as the value for the cooresponding key.

I tried:

```
result = Hash[things.map { |t| t.id, t.value }]
```

where `things` is a list of `Thing`

But this did not work.

Comment: @potashin, I believe "list" implies array.

Comment: What do you mean, "did not work"? Did it return the wrong result? Did it raise an exception? If the latter, what was the exception? I see nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = things.map{|t| {t.id => t.value } }
```

The content of the outer pair of curly brackets is a block, the inner pair forms a hash.
However, if one hash is the desired result (as suggested by Cary Swoveland) this may work:

```
result = things.each_with_object({}){| t, h | h[t.id] = t.value}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Thing
  attr_reader :id, :value
  def initialize(id, value)
    @id = id
    @value = value
  end
end

cat = Thing.new("cat", 9)
  #=> #<Thing:0x007fb86411ad90 @id="cat", @value=9> 
dog = Thing.new("dog",1)
  #=> #<Thing:0x007fb8650e49b0 @id="dog", @value=1> 

instances =[cat, dog]
  #=> [#<Thing:0x007fb86411ad90 @id="cat", @value=9>,
  #    #<Thing:0x007fb8650e49b0 @id="dog", @value=1>] 

instances.map { |i| [i.id, i.value] }.to_h
  #=> {"cat"=>9, "dog"=>1}
```

or, for Ruby versions prior to 2.0:

```
Hash[instances.map { |i| [i.id, i.value] }]
  #=> {"cat"=>9, "dog"=>1}
```